# SteamKit2 Log OutGoing Messages In C#

Tags: c#, logging, steam, steambot, steamworks-api

Any assistance with this would be highly appreciated:

I currently have a sticky situation whereby I can use SteamKit2 to receive and log incoming messages from Steam friends (the code is written in C#) - that is all good and ready to go - however, I have no way of logging outgoing messages being sent either in response to an incoming message or just a message being sent to someone regardless.

After looking online I have been unable to find any solutions for actually tracking/logging/viewing outgoing messages from an account, other than one C++ application which can write to a file both incoming AND outgoing messages.

How would one do it in C# as I do not even know where to start due to no documentation on it.